MODIStsp R package: unable to download land cover data
I am trying to download land cover data using the MODIStsp R package without using the GUI, using the following code:
library(remotes)

remotes::install_github(
  "ropensci/MODIStsp"
)

remotes::install_github(
  "dickoa/rgeoboundaries"
)

remotes::install_github(
  "isciences/exactextractr"
)

libs <- c(
  "MODIStsp", "rgeoboundaries",
  "tidyverse", "sf", "terra",
  "exactextractr", "httr"
)

installed_libs <- libs %in% rownames(
  installed.packages()
)

if(any(installed_libs == F)){
  install.packages(libs[!installed_libs])
}

invisible(lapply(libs, library, character.only = T))

main <- getwd()

file_path <- paste0(
  main, "/", "tth.shp"
)

sf::st_write(
  tth,
  file_path,
  append = FALSE
)

MODIStsp::MODIStsp(
  gui = F,
  out_folder = main,
  out_folder_mod = main,
  selprod = "LandCover_Type_Yearly_500m (MCD12Q1)",
  bandsel = "LC1",
  user = "", # my username
  password = "", # my password
  start_date = "2020.01.01",
  end_date = "2020.12.31",
  spatmeth = "file",
  spafile = file_path,
  out_format = "GTiff"
)

Where tth is a shapefile of a region I an interested in. The code gives the following error:
GDAL version in use: 3.8.5
[Thu Jun 27 16:53:25 2024] MODIStsp --> Starting processing
[Thu Jun 27 16:53:25 2024] Accessing http server at:  https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOTA/MCD12Q1.061/
[Thu Jun 27 16:53:25 2024] Retrieving list of available ` Terra ` Files for Year 2020
Error in MODIStsp_download(modislist, proc_opts$out_folder_mod, download_server,  : 
  Username and/or password are not valid. Please provide
             valid ones!

Although my login credentials are correct (I am currently logged in my NASA Earth Data account):

Any hints as to how to solve this problem would be much appreciated.
